# How to get tab control's header height in an empty control

Tags: winapi

My app's main window contains a Rebar control which contains a menubar band, a toolbar band, and a tab control band. When adding those bands using `RB_INSERTBAND` I have to pass a minimum height for the band in the `cyMinChild` member field of the `REBARBANDINFO` structure. Otherwise the Rebar control doesn't layout its bands correctly.

I can easily calculate the `cyMinChild` for the menubar and toolbar bands by simply using the `TB_GETBUTTONSIZE` message to find out the height of the menubar and toolbar.

For the tab control, however, things are more difficult. In fact, I'm unable to find any way of determining the tab control's header height. The problem is that initially, the tab control doesn't have any entries. If the tab control had some entries, I could just use `TCM_GETITEMRECT` to find out the header size but when I create the tab control and add it into the Rebar control, it doesn't have any entries yet.

So how should I find out the `cyMinChild` height for my tab control? Do I have to insert a dummy entry, grab the height using `TCM_GETITEMRECT`, and instantly remove the dummy entry again to achieve that? Or is there a nicer solution?

Note that I'm not using any toolkits. Everything is done in pure C so any solution should also be in plain Win32 API.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your tab control displaying the tabs at the top? If so, `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` would probably do what you want. I can't remember if I've ever used this with an empty tab control or not.

Comment: Wouldn't that have the same problem as `TCM_GETITEMRECT`, since there are no tabs? Does `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` work correctly with multi-row tab controls? If the latter, then the former...

Comment: @CodyGray: Tried it, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work right for empty tab controls because the width/height that I get from `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` is just 4 pixels.

Comment: Well, I guess that makes sense. It returns the *actual* rectangle, which will be very small for a tab control that has no tabs! I can't play around with this without sample code, but the last time I used a rebar control, I was able to avoid setting the explicit size fields (assuming you don't specify `RBBIM_CHILDSIZE`), and it would automatically resize itself. But if you can't make that work, you're either going to have to insert a dummy tab, or adjust the rebar's height after the first tab gets created (otherwise, it just needs to be tall enough to accommodate its  other children).

Comment: Actually, I've tried a lot to avoid having to set `cyMinChild` but all to no avail. As soon as I leave out `RBBIM_CHILDSIZE`, all of my bands are given a minimal height of maybe 2 pixels or something. If you can tell me how I can get the rebar control to take care of the layout itself, I'd be more than happy to ditch the `cyMinChild` stuff altogether.

Comment: 4 pixels? Were you just looking at `rc.left`? Because that seems to be normal for `rc.left`...

Comment: Well, calling `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` with `wParam` set to FALSE simply added a 4 pixel border to all coordinates, e.g. I passed 0 0 1274 681 and got 4 4 1270 677 back. Not really useful.